# How do I host a Django project on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform

Can anyone tell me how I can easily host my Django Project on Google Cloud Platform ?

Links to a detailed video guide are highly appreciated and Thanks in advance.

I find the documentation so convoluted, tedious, and non-user friendly and so need help to figure out the right way to host my Django based project.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deploy your Django project in the cloud is using a micro VM, or you can use google app engine but I don't have experience with that so I can't help you with that.

First create a VM instace if you don't know how you can [read this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) then you can read this tutorial how to setup a [Django tutorial in a Linux machine](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) . Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform has multiple [product offerings](https://cloud.google.com/products/), you need to decide on one which best fits your particular case.

IMHO you should start here to decide: [Getting Started With Django](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/)